# Win10 IoT Raspberry Pi 3 Dev Board with official 7" Display

Tags: pi-3, display, windows-iot

I am trying to get a Pi 3 Dev board with an official 7" LCD attached to boot into Win10 IOT.  All I am getting is a blank screen.

The screen is plugged in to Disp1 on the dev board. 
I have tested with Raspbian and the screen works when booted in to Linux.

When booting in to Win10 IOT I do not get any display on the LCD.   Eventually I can connect to the device via the remote web interface, so the device is booting but not turning the screen on.

I suspect I just havent attached the appropriate extra jumpers required for Windows.

I understand the screen will work with a Win10 IOT on a Standard Raspberry Pi 3 But I can find little about making it work with a Compute module 3 on Dev board.

I am using the latest build of Win10 IOT.